Looking for the name of a specific story involving Kubera's curse and a group of sages
I am looking for the name of a specific story involving a group of brothers who are all monks/sages and Kubera. It could be from a folktale or from a sacred text, but I do not remember because I read the book it was from years ago and have since lost it. The book was in Telugu.
In the story, a group of 4 (5? I forget) brothers who are all sages set out on a journey to acquire riches. Each of the brothers have a magic lamp wick that they carry in their hands. Whenever a lamp wick falls out of their hands on the ground, it would signify that there was some valuable material buried underneath there. The brothers reach the base of a mountain where a wick falls out of one of their hands. They immediately start digging there and come across a large vein of copper ore. The brother who's wick fell is satisfied and suggests they collect the ore and return home. However, the other brothers are not satisfied and keep going up the mountain until their wicks all fall. They do eventually all fall and the brothers dig up silver, gold, and precious gems. After having collected all of these, 4 of the brothers are satisfied and turn around to go back home, but the last brother is greedy and wants to keep going up the mountain, imagining a treasure greater than any of the previous ones.
As he eventually nears the peak of the mountain, he starts hearing painful screams, as if someone is being tortured. Eventually, he reaches the peak and sees a man with a giant wheel spinning rapidly on his head. The wheel is grinding down his skull, which seems to regenerate endlessly despite the crushing weight of the wheel. When the last brother asks what's going on here, the wheel suddenly flies off the man's head and lands on the brother's head instead. The man who was previously there tells the brother that he was put under a curse by Kubera for seeking his riches and was once a foolish young man like the brother, who was motivated by greed. Now that a new person has come to take his place, the wheel has come off his head and his suffering is over.
